# How do I enable cmake give me the compilation output one screenful at a time instead of just giving me the dump at end

Tags: cmake

I am running cmake version 3.23.2 on Debian teseting. If I put -

```
$cmake .
```

It would generate the output but that's too fast for me to read. If I do something like -

```
cmake . > cmake-build.txt
```

that generates only the last five lines of the build. I never come to know/see if there are any errors, warnings, etc. that need to be reported.

Updated and this is what I get -

```
Platform: Linux
Touchscreen input: No (Enable by param -DENABLE_TOUCHSCREEN=ON)
Metaserver: No (Enable by param -DENABLE_METASERVER=ON)
Doxygen documentation: No (Enable by param -DENABLE_DOC=ON)
Game development files: No (Enable by param -DENABLE_DEV=ON)
Upx packer: No (Enable by param -DENABLE_UPX=ON)
X11: Found and enabled (Disable by param -DWITH_X11=OFF)
==================================
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/shirish/games/Wyrmgus-master
```

Let me share what I did -

```
~/games/Wyrmgus-master$ mkdir build

~/games/Wyrmgus-master$ cd build/

~/games/Wyrmgus-master/build$ cmake ../ | less
```

The third is the crucial command I guess. Here, it just gives me some but not everything, at least something is missing, for e.g. there is something before  -

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
```

I want the few lines before that to be also captured :(

Comment: Did you clean the build between attempts? `cmake .` followed by `cmake . > cmake-build.txt` would just tell you there was nothing much to do in the second attempt. Incidentally, you should really use a separate build tree with CMake (`mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..`).

Comment: I just updated the question and tried to make it build out of tree.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about less!

`program | less` will put the output of `program` through the *pager* called `less`, so you can scroll around it at your leisure.

A word on your `cmake` usage: `cmake .` indicates you're doing an in-tree build. That is practically always a bad idea, because it clutters your source code with your build results. As a matter of fact, much software will simply refuse to build that way!

Better:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. | less
```

And: running cmake twice from the same directory doesn't do anything – the software generation process has been set up after the first time.

Comment: You are right and then we try to make it clean -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680420/looking-for-a-cmake-clean-command-to-clear-up-cmake-output

Comment: that has nothing to do with that. It basically runs `make clean` for you. It does not lead to a repetition of the cmake configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The messages which are missing in the log file are [notices](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html), and CMake outputs those to its standard error.

You need to capture both standard output and standard error:

```
cmake .. |& less
```

You should log standard error along with standard output anyway when keeping an eye on a build: actual error messages would also go to standard error, and those are the messages you really want to see.